# Send a command to a window in a running screen session from a bash script

Tags: bash, command, debian, gnu-screen

I know how I can run a command in a running screen session from the commandline:

```
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff 'top^M'
```

But this and also '\012' instead of the ^M isn´t working from a bash script and the faq and doku doesn´t tell me more:
http://aperiodic.net/screen/faq#i_have_a_nested_screen_session_-_how_do_i_send_screen_commands_to_the_inner_screen

How can I send a command to a running screen session from a bash script ?

Answer (score 4):

Instead try: `screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff $'top\n'`

---

**UPDATE** Sample session:

```
$ cat > test.sh
screen -S test -p 0 -X stuff $'top\n'
$ screen -S test
```

Press ctrl+d to detach.

```
[detached from 25149.test]
$ . test.sh
$ screen -S test -r
```

See `top` running.

Comment: Did you see the sample session in the answer I added? Did you try that exactly?

Comment: I have posted sample session detached, but it works just the same with attached (just leave out the detach then, obviously).

Comment: which version of screen do you use ?

Comment: The package from debian stable `4.1.0~20120320gitdb59704-7`